# Behavioral analysis to find anomalies in Splunk

Tags: ftp, analytics, behavior, splunk, log-analysis

I want to perform Behavioral analysis / anomalies detection in Splunk by comparing Historical (say last months data) with todays data to find anomalies.

I am analyzing FTP logs, so e.g I want to have a historical baseline/report of all users with there IPs/City and logging time. 
Anomalies can be defined as if same user logins from different IP range/City and in different time zone.
Commands: anomalies, anomalousvalue, analyzefields are availbale in Splunk but these commands typically work on a time range of searched data and not compare with the historical data for a user as we want it.

How can I achieve this in Splunk?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running two searches and then joining them together:

1. start by getting the current data and putting it in a simple table: `search | table username ip city time_zone`
2. Prepare the second search and rename the fields (except username) to have different names `second search earliest=-2mon@mon latest=-1mon@mon| table username ip city time_zone | rename ip as old_ip | rename city as old_city ...`
3. Join the searches together: `search | join [ | search second_search ]`
4. Now you can search for users with similar new and historical fields.

Hope it is helpful.